# Setting a child's height to a percentage of the parents height that is using min-height

Tags: html, css

**HTML** code:

```
<div class="parent-one">
   <div class="child-one">
      <p>Some Text...</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** code:

```
.parent-one {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%
}
    
.child-one {
    // min-height: inherit // This works and sets child height to 100vh
    // min-height: 30% // This does not work
    // height: 30% // This does not work
}
```

I have set the *parent's* **min-height** to `100vh` and need to set the *child's* **min-height** (or height) to a *percentage of the parent's min-height*.

From the code example above, I tried 2 ways to achieve this but have not been successful.

Can you please tell me how I should go about setting the child's min-height? and what if I need to set the child's height?

Comment: can you use `height` instead of `min-height` on the parent container?

Comment: @LS_ Nope...has to be min-height

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height#formal_definition: _"The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto."_ - you have no explicitly specified height here.

Answer (score 0):

Set `.parent-one { display: grid; }`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent-one {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: start;
}

.child-one {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 30%;
  /* this works too: */
  /* height: 30%; */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-one">
  <div class="child-one">
    <p>Some Text...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: display: grid is not required on the parent. The trick is to specify a height value explicitly, along with the min-height value. Then the child can simply use a height percentage of the parent's min-height: 100vh.

Comment: Man, `display: grid;` is required just in case you want to push from the parent `min-height`, not from the` height`. As in your code example.

Comment: No, i am able to get the job done with using grid on the parent.

Comment: .parent-one {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.child-one {
  // min-height: 50%; // also works
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.child-two {
  // min-height: 50%; // also works
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 48px;
}

Comment: Sorry about the above comment..Not sure how to format it as code

Comment: Yes, but you still set the `height`. And I will tell you how to do it without set `height`.